# python - assistance with for loop

Tags: python, loops

I'm a complete beginner in Python

I've been banging my head on my keyboard all day just over one thing.

I am logging into a site. If you're successfully logged in, your username will be in the cookies.

```
#other stuff
cookies=requests.Session()
def loggedIn()
     global cookie
     for cookie in cookies.cookies:
             cookie = cookie.value

     if username in cookie:
             print 'yay'
     if username not in cookie:
             print 'goodbye cruel world'

loggedIn()
raw_input()
```

If you are succesfully logged in, the cookie will have 3 values

```
token
username
blabla
```

if you are not succesfully logged in, the cookie will have 2 values

```
token
blabla
```

So I run the code with the correct password and this is what I get:

```
goodbye cruel world
yay
goodbye cruel world
```

with the wrong password:

```
yay
goodbye cruel world
```

This is what I want:

If the username is in the cookie, it will print something once and end the loop

If the username is **not** in the cookie, it will print something once and end the loop.

I'm really confused.

Comment: does your code even work? where does variable username come from? please provide code that works and reflect your problem

Comment: yes, it works, but not how I want it to work. username comes from sys.argv[1]

Comment: In that case, provide the code that deals with sys.argv or make a "username = 'usr'" statement so that your code can run in interpreter. it helps addressing your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
cookies = requests.Session()

def loggedIn():
  for cookie in cookies.cookies:
    if 'username' in cookie.value
      return True
  return False

if loggedIn():
  print 'yay'
else:
  print 'goodbye'
raw_input()
```

Comment: But what if 'username' isn't the username?

Comment: I was under the impression `token`, `username`, and `blabla` were field names.  I might be mistaken there.

Comment: maybe I was mistaken, not you :)

Comment: OP might be able to tell us ;-)

Comment: It worked. whats the purpose of the return False? also, username is a variable :)

Comment: The return False is if 'username' is not in `cookie.value`, because if it is, the first `return` will "break" the if statement, so to speak. `if loggedIn()`, basically is the same as `if loggedIn() == True`... ARGHHHH TOO MANY IF'S

Comment: I step through all cookies, have a look at each to find out whether the username is part of it and if so, I return True.  After the loop I'm sure that no cookie contains the username, so I return False.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for cookie in cookies.cookies:
         cookie = cookie.value
```

Review that code. It is modifying variable `cookie` whose scope is inside the for.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a `for` loop, if you change the variable it is calling, it will use the changed variable, as follows:

```
>>> forever = ['a']
>>> for k in forever:
...    print k
...    forever.append(k)
...
a
a
a
a
a
...
```

This makes it a `while` loop. If you want to stop that, set the variable to something else beforehand:

```
>>> forever = ['a']
>>> duplicate = forever
>>> for k in duplicate:
...    print k
...    forever.append(k)
...
a
>>>
```

So attempt to change your `for` loop, it will hopefully clean everything up

Answer (score 0):

```
 if username in cookie:
         print 'yay'
 else:
         print 'goodbye cruel world'
```

Would make more sense. Also this maybe?

```
 for cookie in cookies.cookies:
         if('user' in cookie):
             print 'User Valid'
 print 'User Invalid'
```